# Is there a way to keep the audio playing on the BBC iPlayer app when the screen is off / locked?

Tags: lock-screens

The BBC sounds app allows this - it will keep playing when you turn the screen off. The iPlayer app doesn't seem to allow this, presumably because the BBC think that you are watching the programme on the screen. However I want to be able to just listen to some programmes like the Sounds app.

Comment: My version of the app does this (BBC iPlayer on my Pixel 8 Pro running Android 14). I did have to say "yes" to the notification access permission, which may allow the app to stay "alive" and active when the screen turns off. Could you check whether or not you have allowed this permission?

Comment: @jlehenbauer, why not make it an answer

Comment: @RohitGupta, if it ends up solving the issue I'll be happy to!

Comment: Xiaomi's MIUI has a special function for that purpose and works with any app.